# Alerting an input value gives undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This HTML is dynamically appended on button click. The input value is being returned `undefined` in the input event handler. Why is this happening?

```js
html += '<div class="div-table-col-unit"> <input type="text"/></div>';

$(document).on('input', '.div-table-col-unit', function(event) {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: a div has no property value

Answer (score 2):

You attached the `input` event to the `div` element; they do not have a `value` to read. You need to bind the event directly to the `input` instead:

```js
let html = '<p>Foo</p>';
html += '<div class="div-table-col-unit"> <input type="text" /></div>';
$('body').append(html);

$(document).on('input', '.div-table-col-unit input', function(event) {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can retain the binding to the `div`, but use the `target` property of the event to reference the element that actually originated the `input` event:

```js
let html = '<p>Foo</p>';
html += '<div class="div-table-col-unit"> <input type="text" /></div>';
$('body').append(html);

$(document).on('input', '.div-table-col-unit', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```